# gSoap MinGW compilation error _set_errno was not declared in this scope

Tags: compiler-errors, mingw, windows-xp, configure, gsoap

I am trying to compile **gsoap_2.8.123** version in windows xp 32 bit (I realize that it is old, but for the project to be carried out I have no alternative)

I use MinGW (installed in `C:\MinGW`)as a compiler and ran mintty with the `msys.bat beautify mintty` command.

Inside mintty I ran `./configure`
So i run `make` and i get the following error

```
In file included from stdsoap2_cpp.cpp:65:0:
stdsoap2_cpp.cpp: In function 'SOCKET soap_accept(soap*)':
stdsoap2.h:1158:40: error: '_set_errno' was not declared in this scope
#  define soap_reset_errno _set_errno(0)
                                    ^
stdsoap2_cpp.cpp:7037:3: note: in expansion of macro 'soap_reset_errno'
soap_reset_errno;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried with `./configure --includedir="C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include"`

or

`./configure --includedir="/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include"`

without success

In `config.log` is reported

```
configure:6317: checking for errno.h
configure:6317: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:6317: $? = 0
configure:6317: result: yes
...
configure:6407: checking for sys/socket.h
configure:6407: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:64:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

******* Update *******

I have installed **msys-gcc** and in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\include` there are the headers I need,

I tried with `./configure --includedir="/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/"`
and I keep getting the error `checking for sys/socket.h ... no`

***** Update *****

To set the include directories I set the environment variable:

```
SET CPPFLAGS=-I"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\include" -I"C:\MinGW\include"
```

and is now used during compilation, as shown below, where it is noted that the _set_errno issue is still present :

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/c/PrgEda/Installazioni/gSoap/gsoap-2.8/gsoap'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -IC:\MinGW\msys\1.0\include -IC:\MinGW\include
-DMINGW -MT libgsoap_a-stdsoap2.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgsoap_a-stdsoap2.Tpo 
-c -o libgsoap_a-stdsoap2.o `test -f 'stdsoap2.c' || echo './'`stdsoap2.c
In file included from stdsoap2.c:65:0:
stdsoap2.c: In function 'soap_accept':
stdsoap2.h:1158:28: warning: implicit declaration of function '_set_errno' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 #  define soap_reset_errno _set_errno(0)
                            ^
stdsoap2.c:7037:3: note: in expansion of macro 'soap_reset_errno'
   soap_reset_errno;
```

******* Update *******

In stdsoap2.h I have replaced

```
#define soap_reset_errno _set_errno(0)
```

with

```
#define soap_reset_errno (errno = ENOENT)
```

and I set

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/ -I/MinGW/include/ -m32 -std=gnu++11 -DWITH_NO_C_LOCALE"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/ -I/MinGW/include/ -m32 -std=gnu++11 -DWITH_NO_C_LOCALE"
```

but now I have this errors:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iterator:64,
                 from stdsoap2.h:752,
                 from stdsoap2_cpp.cpp:65:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:64:11: error: '::mbstate_t' has not been declared
   using ::mbstate_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:141:11: error: '::btowc' has not been declared
   using ::btowc;
           ^~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:142:11: error: '::fgetwc' has not been declared
   using ::fgetwc;
           ^~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:143:11: error: '::fgetws' has not been declared
   using ::fgetws;

...

c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:213:19: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcschr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

...
```

**Update**

I have removed the includes from the **CPPFLAGS** and **CXXFLAGS** variables and now I no longer have the compilation errors

**Update**

With the above indications I was able to compile **soapcpp2.exe**, now I would like to compile **wsdl2h.exe** with ssl support, see [How can I compile gSoap wsdl2h.exe using MinGW with ssl support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73797094/how-can-i-compile-gsoap-wsdl2h-exe-using-mingw-with-ssl-support)

How can i include the correct compile directives using **compile** parameters ?

It seems that the `configure` script does not handle the `includedir` parameter

Comment: `sys/socket.h` doesn't exist in MinGW. But replacing it with `winsock2.h` in the `#include` lines works a lot of the time. I myself am perfectly able to build gSOAP 2.8.123 with MinGW-w64 without tweaking. I use the following `configure` flags: `--enable-gnutls --disable-samples`

Comment: Another thing: use the headers that come with the MinGW/MinGW-w64 you are using. Don't use one MinGW/MinGW-w64 `gcc` while pointing `-I` or `-L` flags to folders of another!

Comment: @BrechtSanders I have tried MinGW/MinGW-w64 , but I have the "not a valid Win32 application" error .

Comment: @BrechtSanders please see the latest update

Comment: GCC 6.3.0 is really very old (current is 12.2.0). Please try a newer MinGW-w64 version, either via MSYS2's pacman package manager or you could try a standalone build from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: @BrechtSanders Thank you for your suggestion, but also the winlibs give me the error"not a valid Win32 application" error.

Comment: Which file exactly is "not a valid Win32 application"? Can you check that file with the "file" command (should be available in MSYS2) which format it reports it be? Also make sure you're not compiling to 64-bit - in Windows X that really is not a valid Win32 application as it doesn't run Windows 64-bit executables.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I dowloaded MSYS2 32 bit from https://repo.msys2.org/distrib/i686/ but when I run mingw32.exe or file.exe I've "AcquireSRWlockExclusive" not found in KERNEL32.dll

Comment: On which Windows version is that?
If it's Windows XP I wouldn't expect it to run, is it's way too old to still use it.